# Xamarin - Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I am currently developing a small Android app in Xamarin, using C#.
The following shows up when I run it on my emulator:
[image: Screenshot of Xamarin error]
This line of code is called when the first tab is selected, which is by default, meaning that this error occurs as soon as I run the program. The XML snippet which seems to be causing the error is this, in one of my layout files:

```
android:background="@color/done"
```

This is in line 111 of Dialer.axml, the entirety of which is below. Here, I am trying to reference a [color state list](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) for my button, so that the color changes depending on whether it is being touched or not. I know that this line causes the error, because removing it from the `button` tag which it's in causes the program to run perfectly. Here is the code for `done.xml`, in my `color` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:color="#ff2222ff"/>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#ff4444ff"/>
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#ff000000"/>
    <item android:color="#ff0000ff"/>
</selector>
```

And here is the code for `Dialer.axml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
    android:background="#2ec0ff">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40sp"
        android:id="@+id/number"
        android:editable="false"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="#fff" />
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="2"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:text="4"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="5"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="6"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button6"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:text="7"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/button7"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="8"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button8"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="9"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/button9"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <Button
            android:text="*"
            android:layout_column="0"
            android:id="@+id/buttonStar"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="0"
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/button0"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        <Button
            android:text="#"
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:id="@+id/buttonPound"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </TableRow>
    <Button
        android:text="Done"
        android:id="@+id/buttonDone"
        android:background="@color/done"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80sp"
        android:textSize="35sp"
        android:layout_margin="5sp" />
</TableLayout>
```

What is causing the error? Am I referencing `done.xml` incorrectly? Did I place it in the wrong folder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the layout for `Resource.Layout.Dialer`?

Comment: @MattR sorry for not doing that right away - I just added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your done.xml is color state list but color state lists can not be used as backgrounds. You need to use state-list-drawable for background.

Here is the state-list-drawable version of your color state list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff2222ff" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff4444ff" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_enabled="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff000000" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff0000ff" /> 
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Put this into an xml file in your drawable file and make your layout button xml like this:

```
android:background="@drawable/done"
```

You can find similar question in this link:
[How to set custom button state background color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14105061/how-to-set-custom-button-state-background-color)

Comment: Thank you, this works! However, for the second item, I had to change android:state_enabled to be "true", otherwise the color would not change at all.

Comment: Yes I realized that was the case but did not want to change that thinking that it might be intentional :)